# Docusign REST API: Downloading document to string

Tags: docusignapi

I am building an app using the docusign API and PHP. I have most of this working except I cannot figure out how to download the document. I have been searching on this site and on the Docusign site. Docusign has an [example here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/get-an-envelope-document-list), that shows how to get a list of docs in PHP, but the downloading does not have a PHP example. In the Docusign REST API docs they explain the [method here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/). But this says the response is "PDF File".

In my sample code below, I have tried to put the contents into a file, but it creates and empty file. If I print_r($data), I get this:

```
      SplFileObject Object
(
    [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] =&gt; /tmp/419ULk
    [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] =&gt; 419ULk
    [openMode:SplFileObject:private] =&gt; w
    [delimiter:SplFileObject:private] =&gt; ,
    [enclosure:SplFileObject:private] =&gt; "
)
```

It does create the file in /tmp, but I want to keep the document in a string so I send or save to DB.

Here is my controller function:

```
public function get_document($envelopeId, $cert = FALSE)
{
    $save_dir = BASEPATH."../documents/";
    if ($envelopeId) {
        $this->load->model('docusign_model');
        $data = $this->docusign_model->get_document($envelopeId, $cert);
    }
    file_put_contents($save_dir.$envelopeId.".pdf", $data);
    //print_r($data);
    die("116");
}
```

This is in docusign_model:

```
public function get_document($envelopeId, $cert)
    {
        $docuSignAuth = $this->auth();
        if ($docuSignAuth) {
            $envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi($docuSignAuth->apiClient);
            $options = new GetDocumentOptions();
            if($cert) {
                $options->setCertificate(TRUE);
            } else {
                $options->setCertificate(FALSE);
            }
            return $envelopeApi->getDocument($docuSignAuth->accountId, 1, $envelopeId, $options);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

How can I get this document and keep it in a string?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: missing the `file_get_contents` of the stream, see answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The content comes back as a file, you have to read the temp file and save that to the desired file

Quick snippet using `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`

```
$docStream = $envelopeApi->getDocument($accountId, 1, $envelopeId);
file_put_contents("my_document.pdf", file_get_contents($docStream->getPathname()));
```

---

More info **[DocuSign REST API :: EnvelopeDocuments: get](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/#examples--Get-a-Single-Document-as-a-PDF-File)** under **Get a Single Document as a PDF File**

Comment: THANK YOU!  The link to "Get a Single Document" just references the call, not how to get the document once it is downloaded. For security this is a little less than idea since it is writing the document to the /tmp directory. I will build it so it removes it immediately, but would be nice if it was just in a stream I could load in a string.

Comment: You're welcome. You could file an issue in the SDK git repo to support that. https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/issues

Comment: hey @Andrew i am using the same code as yours, but when i checkout the file, it is empty. Any idea of the reason behind happening that ?