# Retrieve file from temp on live server

Tags: php, file-get-contents, docusignapi, tmp

I have a file stored in temp folder.
In localhost, when I run the following function:

```
$return_res = $documentRetrieved->getPathname();
```

I get back:

```
C:\Windows\Temp\A2C2.tmp
```

While in live server with the same code, I get:

```
/tmp/cdbQpa
```

When i run

```
file_get_contents($documentRetrieved->getPathname())
```

It works fine in localhost but not in live environment. What should i do so that it works in local and in live server?

Comment: What does it do in live Environment? Do you get an output?

Comment: I get Error: Object Object. (which i assume i can't get anything)

Comment: What content does this file have?

Comment: It's just a document from docusign. Just a pdf file with different details (depends on user)

Comment: you can take a look at this to understand what i am trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309832/docusign-rest-api-downloading-document-to-string