# DocuSign eSign REST API How to handle PDF response in PHP?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to get all documents in an envelope as a single PDF, if I call this REST API URL:

```
/v2/accounts/{$accountId}/envelopes/{$envelopeId}/documents/combined
```

It returns a bunch of data, however, I can't find a way to store this data as a valid PDF. When I output the content with headers it does download a file, but it's not a valid PDF. Also when I store the content in a file, it will not be a valid PDF file.

Anyone encountered this problem and knows how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docusign REST API: Downloading document to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309832/docusign-rest-api-downloading-document-to-string)

Answer (score 0):

The content comes back as a file, you have to read the temp file and save that to the desired file

Quick snippet using `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`

```
$docStream = $envelopeApi->getDocument($accountId, 1, $envelopeId);
file_put_contents("my_document.pdf", file_get_contents($docStream->getPathname()));
```

---

More info **[DocuSign REST API :: EnvelopeDocuments: get](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/#examples--Get-a-Single-Document-as-a-PDF-File)** under **Get a Single Document as a PDF File**